# mongodb getting 10_000 rows at a time

Tags: mongodb, mongo-go

I'm trying to get 10000 document at a time in mongodb, but i got :

Information :

- Driver https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver
- opt.SetBatchSize(15_000)
- opt.SetAllowPartialResults(false)
- index on timestamp

Code :

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

var database *mongo.Database

func main() {

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://20.20.20.43:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    database = client.Database("chat_data")

    chatText := make([]chat, 0)
    now := time.Now().Unix()
    ctx, _ = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)

    // mongodb batch option
    opt := options.Find()
    opt.SetBatchSize(15_000)
    opt.SetAllowPartialResults(false)

    // mongodb filter
    filter := bson.M{"timestamp": bson.M{"$gte": now - 108000}}

    cur, err := database.Collection("chat").Find(ctx, filter, opt)
    if err != nil {
        // fmt.Fprint(w, err)
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer cur.Close(ctx)

    for cur.Next(ctx) {
        var result chat
        err := cur.Decode(&result)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        // do something with result....
        // fmt.Println(result)
        chatText = append(chatText, result)
    }
    if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
        // fmt.Fprint(w, cur.Err())
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("done")
    fmt.Println(len(chatText))
}
```

can i achieve this with mongodb & go driver ?, 30 second timeout are always reached

### Edit 1

i try in python (with pymongo) it's only need `0m2.159s` to query 36k doc with that filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 7000, if it works try 12000, if it doesn't work try 4000, etc.

Make note of how long these requests take to figure out if the execution time is proportional to batch size.

Comment: it's only take 0m2.159s with pymongo

Answer (score 0):

You are querying on just the `timestamp` field.  If you create an index on that collection with the `timestamp` field first, you should get faster results, and get a free sort in the process.

Comment: timestamp already has index, and it's only take 0m2.159s with pymongo

Comment: Sounds like you found a language that suits your need better than Go?